# Network not working properly after restart notebook closed lid

Tags: 16.04, networking, suspend, laptop

I have a notebook on remote location, the notebook has closed lid and from time to time I would like to restart it, but when I do the network doesn't come up, only after the lid is opened.

Second problem and maybe connected is that when the  is closed and no one is logged in into desktop (ssh is not enough) the notebook suspends.

So is there a way how to prevent the notebook from suspending even when no one is logged in and also somehow ensure that the network will reconnect after reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **Settings** -> **Power** and set this screen as follows:

[image: Power lid closed]

Change **When the lid is closed** from `Suspend` to `Do nothing`.

---

### When not logged in

Run this command:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/logind.conf | grep LidSwitch

#HandleLidSwitch=ignore
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
```

Systemd could be suspending the laptop when not signed into Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, thats already set, when the user is logged in the notebook won't suspend, but this I guess apply only  after you log into the ubuntu session.

Comment: @liborw I've added `systemd` option for when not logged in.